# Center a Row Of Images

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I'm trying to align all of the images that are displayed, as a row and center them using flex but I can't seem to figure it out.

I have gotten all the images centred using flex and justify-content center but doing
*flex-direction row* on the container does not do anything, The images remain as vertically stacked columns

I am also using Material UI so if there is a better way to do that with it please let me know.

**Full code - https://pastebin.com/t4wiCexe**
[Cant attach codesandbox as the images are fetched from firebase db, extremely sorry]

Thanks

Home.js

```
<div className="post">
        <img className="postimage" src={post.link} />
  </div>
```

App.css

```
.postimage{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.post{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}
```

[image: rjds]

Comment: Could You please provide link to the repo ?

Comment: Take a look at https://flexboxfroggy.com - this is a great minigame / resource to learn flexbox. I learned a lot.

Comment: Can you give height to the ".post" style?

Comment: you have some other code that spoils everything. the code that you have in the question works as you need - https://codepen.io/aliencash/pen/wvmWMeV

Comment: @AndreyFedorov  please check edited

Comment: Your posted HTML has a surplus `</div>` tag, and you haven't posted a sample of the rendered "*[mcve] code*." Because this is a HTML and CSS question the fact that the DOM is rendered by React is irrelevant, we don't need to see any part of the App *just* the HTML and CSS. Are all the `<img>` elements wrapped together in one `.postImage`, or are they each individually wrapped in a `.postImage`?

Comment: all the Img elements are individually wrapped in a .postimage

Comment: is there a link to your project in the form of a final site? it is better to look for such errors in developer tools in the browser. Apparently you are using flexbox incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap all your images in a Stack component and use it's properties to have the desired result.

```
    <Stack
      direction="row"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      spacing={1}
    >
// start your loop here
   <img className="postimage" src={post.link} />
// your loop stops here
    </Stack>
```

Comment: That does not work sadly please check the images here https://imgur.com/a/upsDPhC

Comment: You have to use the Stack component as mentioned above as a wrapper. So it has to get outside the map() function. Inside the Stack you can have your loop and display the images. I edited the answer with a comment to help more